# Separate /boot partition?

Tags: partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a /boot partition necessary anymore?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6490/is-a-boot-partition-necessary-anymore)

I was told to start partitioning during a Linux install with creating a 300 MB sized /boot partition. Does a separate /boot partition provide any advantages for the average user?

Answer (score 1):

First, 300 Mb is almost certainly going to be too small in the long run.

To answer the question, no the "average" user does not need a separate /boot partition. It is, however, required for certain installations, most common user cases are LVM, Encryption (LUKS) and RAID.