# Size of partitions during Ubuntu install

Tags: hardware, installation, partitioning, hard-drive

I think it would be very helpful to users, if they could know beforehand exactly how much disk space they should allocate while opting for advanced partition method during an Ubuntu installation.

That would be helpful for** `/`, `/boot`, `/home`, `swap` **and other partitions.

Comment: Possibly related to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/247/whats-your-recommendation-on-drive-partitioning-schemes-for-a-desktop-and-home-s

Answer (score 2):

No need to separate **/boot** partition really.

For **/** without /**home** partition, 12-15 GB will be more than sufficient.

For **/home**, it will be where you will be storing all your files, it's more upto you do decide, I personally keep that around 32-35 GB. I suggest you more though.

**SWAP** should be more than the RAM of your system, for instance if you have 2GB RAM, do allocate 2GB+ SWAP space.