# How to reinstall Ubuntu keeping my data intact?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I want to reinstall Ubuntu keeping my data intact. I have 160 GB hardrive (sata or pata I don't know but it's slim and made in China) with a 40 GB ext3 partition, a 4GB swap memory and 3 other partition with a FAT32 file system. I have around 4GB space on my drive where Linux is installed.

I'd like to keep the data intact, especially the Downloads folder, desktop, and `/var/www`; And I no longer have access to any other machines or external storage devices.

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, you also don't have an Ubuntu CD or a USB stick. Correct?

Comment: i don't have DVD-Rom but there is USB port where i installed ubuntu from. Since i don't have ubuntu OS i am downloading one

Comment: last time i made USB bootable and i installed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just copy the directories that you want to save i.e Downloads, `/var/www` and Desktop to another partition, install Ubuntu to that 40 GB ext3 partition and after installation copy the directories back.

Comment: do you mean i can copy files while installing ubuntu? i don't have access to sudo command (it's disabled and the only partition that is accessible to me is the partition where linux is installed and i don't want to delete other drives.)

Comment: @explorex: you have access to all your files when booting a live system from USB or CD

Comment: okay i will try, right now i am downloading one

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific @binW? There's nothing wrong with explaining it in painstaking detail ;-)

Answer (score 4):

In the installer, choose the option for advanced partitioning, then select your existing `/` or `/home` partition. In the box that appears, make sure the filesystem selected matches the existing filesystem of that partition, and that the format box is **not** checked. Proceed as normal through the rest of the options.

Copied from a comment by Evan on a previous Ask Ubuntu question: [What's your recommendation on drive partitioning schemes for a desktop and home server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247/whats-your-recommendation-on-drive-partitioning-schemes-for-a-desktop-and-home-s/3603#3603)

According to the comment this will only preserve `/home`, `/usr/local`, `/usr/src`, and `/var/local`, so you will probably have to move `/var/www` and anything else you want to preserve into your `/home` directory (at least temporarily) to prevent it from being overwritten.