# Window Manager and Login Screen Removed After Trying and Uninstalling Gnome Shell

Tags: unity, gnome, login-screen, metacity, tty

A while back I decided to try the Gnome Shell desktop environment as I've always been a fan of the foundation and the desktop environment. I decided that I'd become used to Unity and that I wouldn't really log into a GNOME session often, so I uninstalled it via the command line... which, frankly, was stupid. When I boot into my Ubuntu installation, the login screen does not appear, but rather a logging TTY - the one seen upon shutdown that is reserved for X11, and normally accessible by Ctrl+Alt+F7. Can anyone tell me the packages required to make the login screen appear - as in default packages that may have been removed (metacity, unity, etc)?

**Edit**: I ran `apt-get update`/`upgrade`/`dist-upgrade` from another terminal, but to no avail.

Here is a picture of the TTY, just in case I was not clear (sorry about the quality):
[image: Ubuntu TTY]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might prove to reinstall the operating system as this may not be a save.

Comment: I was thinking that. I suppose that's what I'll have to do. Is it possible to reinstall without wiping out the home directory - better yet, can one use the Live CD installer to reinstall the default packages and not be left with a bare install?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/19821/46312 look around here

Comment: I ended up just doing a reinstall. Thanks though.

Comment: well that too bad. gave it a good run though.

Answer (score 1):

This should take care of your issue

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

additionally if needed

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Comment: `ubuntu-desktop` was already at its current version, and `gnome-shell` was updated (see my edit of the question).

Comment: is this 10.10, 11.04 or 11.10

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop 11.10 amd64

Comment: try rebooting, during the GRUB boot process, hold down the SHIFT key. This should put you into the recovery console

Comment: Do you mean the GRUB rescue? What would I do from there?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` should install `lightdm` and the rest of the missing packages to get your desktop back.