# How to upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 using usb bootable drive

Tags: 14.04

Currently I am using Ubuntu 12.10. And I want to upgrade to 14.04.

Can I upgrade it using an USB bootable drive without formatting the old OS?

Comment: Yes, you can. But why don't you just upgrade 12.10 to 14.04 from the system itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: @mcantsin - No one can not skip releases when upgrading, so one would go 13.04 -. 13.10, and then 14.04

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Ubuntu LTS 14.04 Trusty Tahr can be upgraded from Ubuntu LTS 12.10 Precice Pangolin directly. From former LTS to latest LTS.

Comment: Because ubuntu 12.10 support will be ended this month only

Comment: 12.10 is not LTS, 12.04 is LTS

Comment: And I do not have to upgrade it to 13.04. Because its support already ended.It will automatically upgrade to 13.10. Now my question is how to upgrade it using usb bootable drive

Comment: By the way ubuntu 12.10 is not a LTS version as far I know

Comment: Upgrading from CDROM / iso is no longer supported.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Re-install Ubuntu without losing data in home folder](http://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/re-install-ubuntu-without-losing-data-in-home-folder)

Comment: or [How to reinstall Ubuntu keeping my data intact?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19808/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-keeping-my-data-intact)

Comment: Reason for doing it this way was the Internet speed was too slow. Because it is a fixed computer it is easier to download 14.04 from a faster Internet connection then at the fixed computer location update from an ISO.

Answer (score 1):

I know that I'm not answering your question about using a USB, but it is much easier to use the steps in this article to upgrade to 14.04. It says 13.10, but it should also work for 12.10.
http://itsfoss.com/upgrade-ubuntu-1404-beta-1310/

Comment: also read http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04

Comment: Neither of those really answer the question as the OP is asking about upgrading from cd / iso .

Comment: I know, but it seems all he cares about is his data being saved. This is just a safer suggestion that will let him upgrade and save his data. However, if he insists on using a USB, then i have totally missed his main concern

Comment: with a fresh install of Ubuntu, the data in /home is preserved, separate partition or not. "Since Hardy it is possible to reinstall Ubuntu without losing the content of the /home folder (the folder that contains program settings, internet bookmarks, emails and all your documents, music, videos and other user files). This can be done even if /home is not on a separate partition " - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation