# Can I install Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet) in place of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and keep all my data (media, documents, etc)?

Tags: boot, ram

I have been using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for the better part of a year, but lately I keep having problems with my OS. I repeatedly get a message about not enough space in the boot, and when I attempt to clean the boot using "sudo apt-get" it miserably fails to do its supposed job every time. 
Not only that, but I am unable to update the OS while using my laptop. So I've decided to install the brand spanking new version of Ubuntu from a USB stick, but I am wary of doing so if it means I will lose all of my private and school related data.

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Did you prviously make your /home under different partition?

Comment: @Pabi the OP is asking about the data and not how to upgrade since he specified he wants to use a USB stick and install brand spanking new version of Ubuntu

Comment: Sorry I missread, provided an answer.

Comment: `sudo apt-get` will not clean the boot. You should specify the entire command you used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reinstall Ubuntu keeping my data intact?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19808/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-keeping-my-data-intact)

Answer (score 0):

If your `/home` is on a different partition you can just install it.
Choose `smoething else` at partitioning and select you current `/home` as `/home` mountpoint. Do not tick reformat!
Choose your current `/` as `/` mountpoiny, tick reformat here.

If your `/home` is on the same partiotioin as `/` you have two options:

Do a backup of your `/home` and copy the data back after the fresh install.

Or shrink your partition and create a new one for `/home`, copy your `/home` there and then select it druing as `/home` mountpoint during the instqallation.