# Is it possible to fix Ubuntu 16.04 by installing Ubuntu 16.04 over the top of the existing Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: update-alternatives

It was easy to install Ubuntu 16.04 over Ubuntu 15.10, and upgrading from version to version has always been easy, until I upgraded to 16.04 which seems to have been corrupted and is now seriously faulty. Software updater, update notifier, synaptic, Ubuntu software, and now even apt-get do not work at all. Internal error warnings are rife. I must fix it or loose 2 years of accumulated progress. Of course I've backed up my data but I can't face re-installation of all the applications (including windows OS) needed should (when) 16.04 fails completely.

I have spent considerable time with Google search but the methods offered all assume more knowledge and familiarity than I obtain. Is there a simple method to simply install 16.04 again over the top of the corrupted 16.04?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reinstall Ubuntu keeping my data intact?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19808/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-keeping-my-data-intact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install Ubuntu 16.04 overtop of an existing 16.04 you won't have to reinstall Windows OS because it's on a separate partition. Just make sure you pick the installation option "Install alongside windows".

The question of how to install overtop an existing version of Ubuntu (without upgrading / conversion pains) is described here: [how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-keeping-my-data-intact](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19808/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-keeping-my-data-intact) Pay close attention to the files that need to be backed up.

Having to reinstall the non-Ubuntu Linux applications you've been using is not necessarily a bad thing because you get fresh, clean, up-to-date non-converted versions of them too.

If you are in doubt of the "new installation" process and have extra space you can shrink the current Ubuntu partition using GParted. Then create a new partition and install a second fresh version of Ubuntu 16.04. Next install all the non-Ubuntu Linux applications you've been using and test them. Of course this takes extra time but gives you peace of mind about the whole installation from scratch process with this trial run.

Comment: Having to reinstall the non-Ubuntu applications is absolutely a bad thing and must be avoided at all costs. The applications are very brittle taking several days for a professional systems administrator to compile successfully, the installation is well beyond my abilities.  The problem is that I use software, I don't write it but those applications were designed and built with Ubuntu as the target OS, so I use Ubuntu.

Comment: In that case a full system backup and restore to a different disk would be the best place way to test the 16.04 reinstall over the upgraded 16.04 with your embedded customized software. It would be best if you talk to the people who created the custom software.