# How big the root partition should be?

Tags: 11.10, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How large should I make root, home, and swap partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21719/how-large-should-i-make-root-home-and-swap-partitions)

When I'm repartitioning my hard disk, how big should the root partition be for flawless functioning?

Even after 6-8 months after installing (v. 10.10), system files on the root partition occupy just 5.7 Gb.

Comment: @belacqua If it is a duplicate question, sorry, I didn't find it before :).  Yet, I think it is important question for users who want to free up HDD space :)

Comment: Oh, no problem if it's a duplicate.  It's good to point other people at all the answers.  If there are better answers that show up here, those can be merged (and I upvoted this as well, since I agree it's a good question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you do with your computer. When you install software, it will be installed in the root partition. It's a very personal thing. For example, I use about 15gb. If you can, with the hard disks that we have today, I suggest you to create a partition about 20gb for your root.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I am using my laptop for daily tasks at university. Mostly for writing, some calculus (Calc), e-mailing. Sometimes I am editing video, RAW photos, video converting, and DVD burning. Most of my tasks (98%) I do in Ubuntu (now 10.10 and 11.10).

Comment: I think 15 Gb will be enough for now :).

Answer (score 1):

To continue with eNry's answer, in my case I'm using 60Gb. I know that is A LOT, but I tend to install a lot of software, including tools for development, audio editing and academic work. Last time I had a root part with 40Gb that got almost full... and my data was in other partition!

Answer (score 0):

I use 15gb for my root partition, and 2.8gb for swap space, it is entirely up to you though and as mentioned above, a, very personal, taste....

Comment: Thank you for recommendations. I use the same partitioning except 4 Gb Swap space (for eventual system hybernation. I didn't try for 11.10 :) )