# Rough guide on how to partition when installing ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, partitioning, mount, ssd, drive

I was wondering if someone could give a rough guide on how to partition my desktop.
I have a 512 GB SSD and 2 TB SATA HDD.
The computer runs on 32 GB RAM and an i7 processor.
The computer is for general purpose and if anyone could detail how I should divide my partitions and where I should mount them I would appreciate it.

Comment: These two posts together should help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/247/whats-your-recommendation-on-drive-partitioning-schemes-for-a-desktop-and-home and http://askubuntu.com/questions/21719/how-large-should-i-make-root-home-and-swap-partitions

Comment: Consider using LVM2. It allows you to resize your logical volumes much easier than partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with the Ubuntu default or the following makes sense:

```
Swap - 2GB
/ (a.k.a. "root") - 50GB
/home - the remainder
```

The swap is perhaps excessive but since we don't know your future memory consumption at installation, why not be generous/prudent with 512GB?

The root ("/") is where your system and other program files will go and 50GB is more than sufficent.

The rest is for "home", where all your user files will go.

You can do all this via the "do something else" option in the Ubuntu installer, or in advance with GParted live (stick it on a USB - it's a mini Debian with GParted on it).

If you go with the Ubuntu default (assuming you want to occupy the whole disk), it will create a swap and also a root partion that occupies the whole disk. This is fine but having a separate home partition is better should you have problems later on.

Comment: @anthony, You may choose this as the answer to your problem, if it has solved it for you.