# Why system partition gets overfull quickly?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

About 2 months ago I've installed ubuntu 12.04 on a new computer. I remember, there were some problems with disc sectors, unfortunately I can't remember now on what it consisted.

I have 15 GB for \ and the rest for \home (total disc space - 320GB). I was pretty sure it's enough. But today after I've installed updates (kernel updates included), I couldn't restart the computer. There was an information, that the \ partition is full, so the computer will be working in low graphic mode, but the next window was not active, so I couldn't enter "low graphics mode". Now I'm working on trial version of ubuntu, using install usb drive.

I don't know how to change the size of the partitions now, but beside that I'm not sure if this would be the solution since I'm not sure if the partition is really full - during the installation, I've made this partition much bigger that it was said in the tutorial and I don't have any special applications (ubuntu, latex, some other small stuff).

In "proprieties" of the system partition is said that total capacity is 15,1 GB and 15,1 GB is used. The output of `df -h` is:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow           1008M  146M  811M  16% /
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           778M  876K  778M   1% /run
/dev/sdb1       1.9G  1.7G  177M  91% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      663M  663M     0 100% /rofs
tmpfs           1.9G  8.0K  1.9G   1% /tmp
none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none            1.9G   80K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda1        15G   14G     0 100% /media/adc83ce8-fc1e-447c-a61c-f69fc0e15ecc
/dev/sda6       278G   83G  181G  32% /media/485f3e29-355c-4be3-b80a-1f5abd5604b6
```

Thanks for any suggestions

UPDATE

I've followed Saurav's Kumar and oldfred's suggestions.

After this I've recovered about 800 MB of free space. Still I don't understand why my system takes so much space. I'm hesitating a bit with "scary" suggestion of mikewather, but maybe I'll have to take a risk :) Or is there anything else I could do, less "scary "?

UPDATE:

I'm reopening the question since the problem persist. Last time, when I managed to boot my computer, I've made `/` bigger, but now I have once again full system partition, I don't know why. I wanted to reinstall the system (there are some problems that I don't know how to "divide" in separate questions and I need my computer working quickly). I've downloaded the `.iso` file for Ubuntu 14.04 - and the system partition got full again. I thought since it's not installation but download, it should be on `/home` and not `/`, so why there is no more space after downloading it? And why 25 GB is not enough for `/`? I didn't install any important things since that time.

In any case I'd like to re-install the system, but I'd like to know why it's happening to avoid the same mistake during the new installation.

According to the replies to [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21719/how-large-should-i-make-root-home-and-swap-partitions), my root partition is huge and I didn't install anything important since one year (since the time I changed it's size from 15 to 25 GB).

Thanks

Comment: Hi Maria!! I've posted your solution in my answer.. Check it out. Please reply if you need any further assistance..

Answer (score 1):

**You can solve your issue using `Recovery Mode`**

Only thing you have to do is to remove some junked files/folders from `/dev/sda1` i,e where you have installed `Ubuntu`

Follow these simple steps:

- Reboot your system and chose `Recovery Mode` (Safe Mode) *2nd option* in Grub Menu.
- Select **grub** option from the list (chose `yes` for the question)
- Then go to **root** in order to login as `root`
- Then execute these commands in series in order to free some spaces..

  ```
  # apt-get autoclean
  # apt-get autoremove
  # apt-get clean
  ```

  `apt-get clean` will remove packages that left after installing any package. So don't worry for that..
- Then go to your `Your Home` directory and remove following directories ( I'm assuming that your Ubuntu's User name is 'maria`):

  ```
  # cd /home/maria
  # rm -r .config .local .cache .fontconfig
  ```

  Above command will remove only your `Users` settings and Web history that you surfed using any web browser. So don't worry for that.. Your system will become new.
- Then reboot your system:

  ```
  # reboot
  ```

Hope after rebooting your problem would be solved. Reply for further assistance..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just don't know how can I modify grub settings now. And since I have just one system, it was not showing up. I don't know how can I change the time the grub is showing up, booting from install usb drive...

Comment: @maria: Oho..! Got it.. You can get your `Grub Menu` by holding `Shift` key when your system starts.. If you still don't get `Grub` then you can boot through `USB` and delete files `.config` `.local` `.cache` etc.. from your older system.. I am sure this time you'll get your `Grub Menu`..

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have some good suggestions. But you also need to see why you used so much. If you have not installed a lot of very large applications you should not have used that much space.  A 15GB root, while not generous is large enough for most users. I actually use about 7GB with a fair number of apps installed.

Sometimes a running system has errors and keeps posting into log file and log files then fill system. I would check that.
If you can boot after minor houseclean:

```
cd /var/log
```

review for very large file & remove log files if no issues

```
sudo rm -f messages.*
sudo rm -v /var/log/*.gz
```

Lots more details:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoverLostDiskSpace

Otherwise you need to review if you have some very large files.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the recovery mode, and the following two commands to free some space:

```
sudo apt-get clean

dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

The first one deletes cached installation files, and should free a few hundred MB. The [second (long and scary)](https://askubuntu.com/a/65104/20054) removes all unused kernels and headers.