# After Installing Ubuntu 13.04 Not able to see options for Windows 8 and Ubuntu at Start Up

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2

Today i installed Ubuntu along with Windows 8 on my HP laptop using DVD Drive (Boot from Internal DVD).

During installation it said something like "You need to have space of 1 MB or so for booting else also you can install it might give errors later"

Issue:
Now i wont get option when systems boots up it directly goes to Windows 8.

I have C Drive 320 GB for Windows, D as 8 GB for Swap, F as 16 GB for /home and 30 GB for Windows recovery.

Please help me, do i need to try boot repair with Try ubuntu option that i get when i boot from DVD?

Waiting for response.

I guess issue is related to MBR, i guess during my installation instead of writing to Windows MBR it wrote to F Drive?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

When you install, make room for "/" for all your system data.  It looks like you only allocated /home and swap space.  I'm guessing it said you have <1MB because there was no partition for /.  Here is [a post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21719/how-large-should-i-make-root-home-and-swap-partitions) on here about it.

Here is [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/powerpc/apcs03.html) on it as well

I personally use swap space, /, /home, and /boot.  But I think only the first two are required.