# "no root file system is defined" error on my new custom built pc

Tags: installation, partitioning

I finished the hardware of the pc about a week ago and I decided to try linux on it so I found a program that will extract Ubuntu on to my flash drive, I extracted it and inserted my flash drive in the computer. BIOS then identifies it and I go into the installation menu, after a few slides it gets to the installation slide with partitions but doesn't have anything on the partition chart. I can't press revert, edit, partition, or anything. I can only press install, back, or quit. When I press install it gives me a "no root file system is defined" error and I don't know what to do after that. Can someone please help me in this problem, I certainly don't want windows and I've never been a fan of it lol.

Comment: install gparted and upload its screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell where you need to install ubuntu.

To specify that, select an option (something like) "I want to do something else" and then select the partition where you want to install ubuntu and from the drop down menu, select `/`.

This question may help you a bit more: [How large should I make root, home, and swap partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21719/how-large-should-i-make-root-home-and-swap-partitions)