# number of partition problem - max 4 - Installation along windows 10 (legacy bios)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10, bios

I am very surprise to not found the answer to my question.. I searched but can't reached the answer, so if it exist on the forum just tell me... (i am not used to this kind of research..)

I have win 10, I shrink my ssd then prepared a partition about 200gb for ubuntu, I booted on an usb drive, my pc is a lenovo t440p, processor i5, 16gb ram, and I tried to follow install tutos (like this one https://techfoss.net/install-ubuntu-along-with-windows-in-dual-boot/ )

The tuto asks to build:
/ (root) – 10 GB
SWAP – 4GB
/home – Remaining (here 86GB)

But in reality I can build the  "/ (root)" and after i am stuck because the freespace is now called: "unusable memory".

I learned on internet that windows 10 accept only 4 partitions and use already 3 of them !!
but Ubuntu needs 3 partitions too !!!
And now I don't know how to create my 3 needed additional partition for ubuntu install as the max available is 4..

Is there someone that know a similar post I missed, or have the answer..

Thanks, Louis

Comment: You can easily install Ubuntu in a single `/`-partition, there is no need to use extra partitions for swap and /home. Since you have only 100 GB available, I'd recommend to do so.

Comment: If new system, you should be installing both Windows & Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode with gpt partitions. Only the 35 year old BIOS boot configuration needs MBR which has the 4 primary partition limit. One of the kluges was to create an extended partition to allow additional logical partitions. With gpt your default limit is 128 partitions, but even that can be increased. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do, thanks to mook765 and oldfred comments. I did not know the MBR/UEFI differences.

SOLUTION: I transform my windows 10 disk in GPT using the command line MBR2GPT (well described here: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-convert-mbr-disk-gpt-move-bios-uefi-windows-10 ), Then I was able to have the number of partition I wanted. This procedure does not erase any windows or personal data and it takes not more than 3 minutes total.

to decide the partitions to do this post was very interesting: 
[How large should I make root, home, and swap partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21719/how-large-should-i-make-root-home-and-swap-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

Make the non root files first with the setting of last, then add the /root to the beginning. This worked for me. It took me a while to figure it out since no one posted this when I did my own digging.

Comment: Because someone was so quick to give me a negative, I did it again to be certain. It works as it should. I do not know why it lists it as unusable memory when you just created the partition after you set the /root first but it does work if you set your swap & home partitions then the root.

Comment: the answer is very unclear. What do you mean by "Make the non root files first with the setting of last"?

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions - which you already did - is to change MBR partitioning to GPT.

But even if you stay with MBR, you can have more than 4 partitions. MBR allows for maximum 4 **primary or extended** partitions (there can be at most one extended partition). The extended partition is the way to overcome the 4 partitions limit: The extended partition is a "container" that can hold more partitions. So you can have for example 3 primary and one extended partition and have more partitions (they are called **logical** partitions) inside the extended partition. Logical partitions are exactly as good as primary partitions to install the system on.