# do i need to create separate partitions such as boot,home,swap for xubuntu 20.04?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, xubuntu

i am average user and want delete windows to install xubuntu as main OS.
after ubuntu 18.04 swap partition replaced with swap file,so do i need to create  swap partition??
also boot or home partitions?

Comment: No, just let the installer do its job unless you particularly want a separate home partition for reasons that make sense to you. There are positives and negatives regarding separate home partitions so its a personal choice

Comment: You absolutely don't have to. Most normal users are satisfied with a setup where everything is on a single partition. Just be sure to keep an eye on disk usage, so logs or user data don't suddenly explode in size.

Comment: The only two partitions you must have is an EFI, which you should already for Windows, and a /(root) partition.  Some people like to have /home  also, but not needed.

Comment: One of the main reasons Ubuntu is popular is it's sane, safe defaults, and that includes the installer. For your first install, stick to the default settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How large should I make root, home, and swap partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21719/how-large-should-i-make-root-home-and-swap-partitions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Ubuntu on a single partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973252/installing-ubuntu-on-a-single-partition)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use separate swap, boot and home partitions. You can join all 3 together with the root partition, although I recommend setting a swap partition for virtual RAM that can make the system faster. Just make sure the disk usage doesn't explode, as Artur Meinild said.