# What is the size of /home and /root partition that i should allocate on my ubuntu machine

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, home-directory, 22.10

I have 280 Gb of storage on my laptop and i am installing ubuntu on my laptop and i plan on utilising the full space and i wanted to know that the partitioning should be like with the exact space that should be alloted? please help me figure out what the partitioning should look like .

i was planning on going with 60 Gb for /root and 10 Gb for swap and the rest for home and i'm kind-of confused right now cause i am not able to exactly figure out if that should be enough because i don't want to reformat the entire system again .
and which one of these should have a larger partition

Comment: 10GB swap is probably unnecessary if you have enough ram. I used to leave 5GB as swap, a decade ago for an entry point if the system ever failed and I needed to install to that space. you can put home and root in the same partition. which is what happens anyway if you dont select the advanced install option.

Comment: You've not said if you're asking about Ubuntu Server & Ubuntu Desktop, as that would be the first detail I'd consider.  I say 60GB for / is overkill (*and I like to bloat my desktops more than most I believe; 32GB is my preferred minimum but I'd likely use 40GB if you've loads of disk space, not more though!*) but how you'll use the box will determine what size should be, and you've not said!  For *swap* I'd consider your RAM & what you'll use the box for, so I have no idea given the details you've provided.

Comment: re: Swap...   If you're only installing a single OS on your box, I'd just use a *swapfile* (no swap partition), which will means yes your / should be increased by whatever you want the *swapfile* size to be, but I'd use that over swap partition.  I still use *swap partition* on my current system, plus others - but that's because the space can be used by whatever OS I'm using (ie. *I don't have 4 swapfiles on my 4 OSes on this box*).  Swap files are similar; and KISS (*Keep it Simple..*) is usually best.  You can change partition sizes if you need to anyway; so don't stress about it.

Comment: FYI, here's the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop) to install Ubuntu. Note that manual partitioning isn't addressed because it's simply not necessary for the overwhelming majority of installations. If you don't already have a specific use case for needing separate partitions, don't worry about it. There's a lot of anecdotal and outdated advice about partitioning floating out there. In general, it's best to adhere to official documentation unless you have a special needs case.

Comment: Please be aware that `/` is the ROOT partition, where as `/root` refers to something very different (it's a user directory for the root user).   (Maybe helpful in understanding Nmath's comment; you need `/` but not `/root`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Ubuntu on a single partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973252/installing-ubuntu-on-a-single-partition)

Comment: Also worth reading, [How large should I make root, home, and swap partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21719/1165986).  It's an oldie, but the accepted answer there is still useful today.