# What is the recommended partition set up?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's your recommendation on drive partitioning schemes for a desktop and home server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247/whats-your-recommendation-on-drive-partitioning-schemes-for-a-desktop-and-home-s)

Hi all,
        I was surfing and I noticed a page talking about a separate /data partition. Now I'd always separated my /home partition for an easier transition to a new Ubuntu installation.

What is the recommended partition set up for the smoothest Ubuntu experience?

Answer (score 1):

For smoothest experience, you should use only single partition (+ probably boot + definitely swap).

### Advantages

You don't have to care about disk sizes. With multiple partitions, if you reserve 10GB for root partition, then it's getting too small if you install few larger programs, and do not clean up log files and so on. That's not really smooth.

Distribution upgrade do not require separate `/data` or `/home` partition. If you want to change distribution (from Ubuntu to Debian or something), then it's useful.

### Disadvantages

If you fill your home folder with some files, whole system will have problems. My experience says that without software RAID5 or RAID6 you do not have problems with that (you can still boot and then delete files), but it's anyway annoying.

---

Also, you shouldn't create new folders to root directory. There is [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html).

> ... must never create or require special files or subdirectories in the root directory. Other locations in the FHS hierarchy provide more than enough flexibility for any package.

Answer (score 0):

That entirely depends on what you're doing with it. For most uses, I go for a 10-40 GB /, swap equalling 2x system memory, and a bunch for /home, but if I was running a server on it, something where a mail queue or system logs could get big on you, I'd throw /var into a separate partition, too.

Otherwise, I'm with Olli