# Installation process

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning, hard-drive, ntfs

I want to install ubuntu 12.04 in hdd ,there is no other Operating System available in my hard disk.So will U please tell me ,the complete process that how to make partition in the hard disk....

The main problem is that what should Type for the hard disk part and what should be the mount point for the each disk part...

My total hard disk space is 500 GB. and I want to make 3 part of it.
part 1: 75 gb : for make it syste drive
part 2: 200 gb : ntfs
part 3: 225 gb : ntfs

And yeah in the disk type ,there is no option like ntfs ,so what other option shold I select for other partition.....

Waiting for the affirmative   reply..!!!!

Comment: Could you edit your question and include why you want this specific partition scheme? Are you planning to install Windows in the future or Do you want to take the hard drive out of this computer and attach it to a Windows computer? Also include in the question what you want to use the computer for. For excample, is it for desktop use, or developing websites etc.? NTFS is for Windows & does not preserve Ubuntu file and folder owenerships. Ubuntu uses ext4 partitions. You may also want a `swap` partition in Ubuntu. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/53699/disk-partitioning for some ideas.

Comment: Also see [Best partitions for normal users](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107599/best-disk-partition-for-normal-users).

Comment: Maybe it possible to install windows in the future...and
should I have to include /boot partition while installation??
And Yeah I'm computer engg. and I want to use for developing website and other programming stuffs..!!

Comment: Then I suggest you install Windows first. Windows do not like Ubuntu and will mess it up.

Comment: Since you are new to Ubuntu, go with the default installation process and let Ubuntu do the partitioning for you. This will delete everything in the entire 500GB disk. Once you are familiar with Ubuntu, you can shrink the default `/` partition and create a `/home` or other partitions.

Comment: If suppose I'll install windows first and then how could I install the ubuntu in the other drive than windows system drive?

Comment: Ubuntu does not use C drive D drive etc for its partitions. After you install Windows, you can shrink the C Drive (or D Drive) to make some space for Ubuntu. When you install Ubuntu, it will find the space and make its own partitions there. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/204686/ubuntu-installation-on-windows7-with-d-partition

Comment: hey,is there some other place where we can chat..!!!
Its really hard to define my past problem related to shrink volume
<br>Facebook or gmail will be very good..!!

Comment: Apparently you don't have enough reputation to chat. Let me give you some.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10455/discussion-between-user68186-and-chudamani)

Comment: Lol...!!!Even though I have 23 reputation ,it wont allow me to chat !!! :P

Answer (score 0):

You will start the installation with a live-stick or live-CD. Choose install ubuntu. when it comes to partitioning, don't hesitate to manually partition your hdd, since you don't have to loose any data. Now you create the first Partition. leave the configs alone, just adjust the size and set the mount point to `/`, so it will be your system partition.

Create Partition 2. (again, no config changes, just the size.) If you want to store your data in `/home` AND `/home` should be on the second (data) partition, you can set the mount point of partition 2 to `/home`. If you do so, everything saved in `/home/` like your personal settings and files will be on the second partition.

during install there's no NTFS-support. At this point that really isn't needed. If you really want to have a NTFS partition, create it later and leave the rest of the HDD-space empty. You can create the partition later during Windows-installation or by installing the NTFS-Tools and a partition manager like `gparted` . ***It is highly recommended to install Windows before ubuntu. Windows DOES NOT create any settings for ubuntu. It will be like you dont have it installed. Ubuntu in the other hand KNOWS all configs for windows and will create a boot manager to choose the booted system automatically on ubuntu install. ***

Hope this helped.