# Saving to data partition, but eating into c:\

Tags: partitioning

I've been saving GIMP files to my separate d: partition but I am getting low disk space warnings for c:

and have just received notice for a LibreOffice document which I am also running off the separate data partition. The partition has 43GB space left, whilst my c:\ is whittled away now to 40MB of free space!

I have a LibreOffice file currently open which reads:

" LibreOffice could not save important internal information due to insufficient free disk space at the following location:
/home/jonno/.config/libreoffice/3/user/backup

You will not be able to continue working with LibreOffice without allocating more free disk space at that location."

How can I free up space on my c: and ensure that saving to d: will not affect c: space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux doesn't use drive letters, so at first I thought you were talking about two Windows partitions (`C:` and `D:`); but I suspect you're actually talking about the Linux root (`/`) partition and a separate Linux data partition. If so, you should re-phrase your question.

Proceeding on the assumption that my re-interpretation of your question is correct, every user of a Linux system has a home directory, which is placed in a subdirectory of `/home` by default -- `/home/jonno` in your case. User files go there by default. Although you can use another partition for storing data files, some files *will* go there anyhow. These include configuration files, some temporary files, Web browser history files, etc. If you didn't allocate much space for your root (`/`) partition, this can chew up enough space to make it run out of space. Certain system and temporary files stored outside of `/home` can do the same. For instance, the `/tmp` directory holds temporary files, and some programs can create pretty big temporary files; and some programs will store big files in subdirectories of `/var`, too.

If you want to use a separate Linux partition for storing user files, the usual approach is to mount it at `/home`. That will help you predict the size of the remaining root (`/`) partition. There are lots of questions and answers on this site about using a separate `/home` partition, such as:

- [What are the pros and cons of having a separate home partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142695/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-having-a-separate-home-partition)
- [I created a separate /home partition, is this a good idea?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92610/i-created-a-separate-home-partition-is-this-a-good-idea)
- [Advantages of separate /home partition on HDD + SSD setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258259/advantages-of-separate-home-partition-on-hdd-ssd-setup)
- [How large should I make root, home, and swap partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21719/how-large-should-i-make-root-home-and-swap-partitions)
- [How to re-mount a different partition as /home?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20287/how-to-re-mount-a-different-partition-as-home)

Note that if you're dual-booting and want to use a common Windows/Linux area for user files, it should *not* be mounted at `/home`, because the most common filesystems for this purpose (FAT and NTFS) lack critical features that are needed in user home directories. In this case, you should keep using your system as it is, but you'll probably have to re-size your Linux root (`/`) partition or take steps to clean up temporary or other unwanted files.

It's hard to advise you about your specific situation without more information. I recommend you edit your post to include the output of the following two commands:

```
sudo parted -l
df -h
```

**Add four spaces at the start of each line of output from these commands.** This will keep the formatting intact; without these spaces, the output will be virtually illegible.