# Partitioning questions

Tags: partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's your recommendation on drive partitioning schemes for a desktop and home server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247/whats-your-recommendation-on-drive-partitioning-schemes-for-a-desktop-and-home)

I'm new to ubuntu/linux and i'd like to create a similar partitioning situation as I had on my old windows machine:

I have one HD of 640GB, split up in 2 partitions: 100GB and 540GB
The first one was dedicated to the OS and software
The second one for storage of personal/media files.

Can someone please explain in laymen's terms what i exactly have to do to create a similar situaton in ubuntu?

many thanks in advance for your guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my set up I usually have three partitions,

- The first partition mounts the root (/) directory (the OS files)
- The second partition mounts the home directory (/home) (personal files)
- The third is for swap space

The main benefit of this is that I can perform a clean upgrade of Ubuntu without it affecting my personal files. I can also install another Linux distribution alongside Ubuntu which will share the home directory.

When you're installing Ubuntu you can set these partitions up in the partition editor by specifying partitions manually. I've usually assigned 10GB to the root partition and never had any space issues; the swap partition can be up to you but 2GB would be sufficient; the home partition would occupy the remaining space.

I'm assuming you're not dual booting so please correct me if I'm wrong!