# Replacing windows od drive with ubuntu

Tags: installation

I have Windows 7 in my system. I want to replace it with Ubuntu without losing any of my data in other drives. Is it possible?

Comment: Also see [Is there any risk on replace Windows 8 with Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/306452/is-there-any-risk-on-replace-windows-8-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! To do this you have to boot into the live CD and in the installation GUI you have to select "Something Else" option when it asks you how to install. After that you can modify your drives and partitions to your liking. That's the safe way.  You can also do it the easy way by select the option to replace your existing OS.

[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaQ3N.png)

Comment: Hi leszakk Thanks for the answer.
can u give me more information. I have followed the installation given in the ubuntu site but i didn't find the options that your are mentiond.