# From Windows 7 to Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows, files, flash

At present, I use Windows 7. I want to delete it and replace it with Ubuntu but, how can I install Ubuntu without losing my files that exist now on partitions D, E and F?

I want my hard disk to be for Ubuntu only, but I want my files still be there. NB: I don't know any thing about partitions editing or Ubuntu codes. Please help me.

Would i be able to use my flash memory after I install Ubuntu? Would I be able to copy files from a Windows PC and pasting it in my Ubuntu PC?

Thanks :)

Comment: I always say this and will keep on doing it: make two backups of your files before touching your partitions.

Comment: Hi and welcome to ubuntu. In future its better to split this 2 questions. 

On your second question: yes, you can copy your windows files from flash to Ubuntu after installation. But beware: files that are connected to dedicated windows programs may not run in ubuntu because such a program may not exist. But things like video's, pictures and most text files will be usable in Ubuntu.

Gd luck

Comment: thank you too much for all , i feel you as my new family ^_^ ♥ , a little another question : i don't konw the codes that linux users use . they usually use codes like cp and mv .. etc : can i use ubuntu without knowing these codes ?? finally : do you think ubuntu is easy to use ?? ♥ ♥ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [If I chose "Replace Windows with Ubuntu", do I lose the other partition too?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306452/is-there-any-risk-on-replace-windows-8-with-ubuntu) for a similar question.

**Here is a step by step direction for you**

**Step one:** Make two backup copies of all the files and folders from all the partitions in your computer. Since you will not be restoring them in a Windows system, **do not use any Windows backup program to make backup.** Use **Copy** to copy the folders. Make two copies preferably in two external USB hard drives.

**Step two:** Download and prepare the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and boot from it. Use the **Try Ubuntu without installing** option. Once Ubuntu loads make sure all the different parts of the computer works. Then plug in the USB drive where you made the backup and make sure you can read and open some of the files. **If this step fails go back to step one.**

**Step three:** click on "Install Ubuntu" only when you are satisfied with steps one and two. Use the "Replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu" option during Ubuntu installation.

**Warning:** This option will delete all the partitions in your hard drive and you will lose all the data.

Once Ubuntu is installed. You will be able to copy back the all the files and folders from the external hard drive into their respective folders within Ubuntu's /home/[user]/ folder.

**Answer to your second question:** Ubuntu can read most USB drives. However, you can test this while you are trying Ubuntu without installing.

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you too much for all , i feel you as my new family ^_^ ♥ , a little another question : i don't konw the codes that linux users use . they usually use codes like cp and mv .. etc : can i use ubuntu without knowing these codes ?? finally : do you think ubuntu is easy to use ?? ♥ ♥ :)

Comment: You are welcome. If you find the answer above to be correct, please consider accepting it as such and put a green check mark on the left. This will help other users. I strongly recommend you first **try without installing** and see if you find it easy to use or not. You can do almost everything with a mouse in Ubuntu. However, it takes longer to give directions about pointing and clicking, so you will find experienced users in forums will often help with command line codes.

Comment: but : when i use ubuntu with the mouse only : will this be similar to using windows with the mouse ??

Comment: There are similarities and differences. It is best to try and find out for yourself. If you cannot figure out how to do something ask a new question in this forum. Or better still search before asking, as someone else may have had asked a similar question before. Best of luck.

Comment: i don't know you , but you just became my first teacher at ubuntu :) TQ very much ♥ :)

Comment: As to answer your question on operating Ubuntu solely by mouse: It's entirely possible. You won't be able to do some of the advanced stuff, but if you don't want to, you do not have to type any commands into the terminal. Many instructions on this site and other sites, however, are terminal-centric instructions. It is therefore beneficial that you know how to operate the terminal, but not necessary.