# Installation of Ubuntu without formatting C drive

Tags: installation

I am using windows 7 and now I thought of installing Ubuntu. So my question is: I want to install Ubuntu in the same C drive without formatting it as we can install Windows 7 without actually formatting Windows XP by simply just upgrading.

Is there any feature available like that?

Summmary: I need to install Ubuntu without formatting my hard disk and please note I don't want to have a dual OS.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/306452/is-there-any-risk-on-replace-windows-8-with-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

No, Ubuntu is not a new version of Windows, so you can't simply upgrade from an existing version of Windows to it. It is a different operating system. You will have to have both systems installed by resizing the existing Windows partition and creating a new one for Ubuntu, or you can replace Windows completely by dedicating the entire disk to Ubuntu.

If there is important data you wish to keep, you should create a backup of that data on an external drive first, and then proceed to install Ubuntu and get rid of Windows, if you only want one OS on the computer.