# Data on hard drive

Tags: system-installation

I have a laptop that's having some is problems with windows 7 tried everything but can't get it to come up with out have the original cd this is where Ubuntu comes in I'm making the switch but I want to know since I will be booting from the cd or USB and installing it on the computer what about the old data that was originally on the hard drive will it be over written (this is what I want) or will have have to wipe the hard drive and then install Ubuntu?

Comment: Note all your data on the hard drive may be erased. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/306452/is-there-any-risk-on-replace-windows-8-with-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you install on the same partition (your harddrive may be one partition) or you choose a new collection of partitions it will format those before installing (ubuntu likes to install on ext2 not ntfs). Formatting destroys data.

This guide says that there will be an option to replace the windows 7 and that it will delete all your programs and files
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest

Comment: ext4 these days. ext2 and even ext3 are old already.

Answer (score 0):

When installing Ubuntu, a selection screen will eventually come up asking you how you would like to install it. One of these options is to wipe the disk and install (or something like that). This will completely remove all data and install Ubuntu in place.

So, yes, all the old data that was originally on the hard drive will be overwritten.