# What about the other partition after installing?

Tags: installation, partitioning

I am going to install Ubuntu 13.04-x64 on my PC. Currently, I have two hard disk partitions as "C" on which I have my windows 8 installed and "D" which contain all my personal files. I having no problem formating or erasing "C" since I am not going to switch back to Windows.
The weired thing happened after I installed Ubuntu on "C" that I can not see the other partition "D" in Ubuntu system. Thanks god that I forced to switch back to windows to check the other partition and still not touched as I was aware that it might be removed during installation of Ubuntu.

I need a tip to install Ubuntu and exploring both Partitions inside like as it in windows. Any help guys ?

For note that I am going to install Ubuntu from a DVD ;)

Comment: See [Is there any risk on replace Windows 8 with Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/306452/is-there-any-risk-on-replace-windows-8-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

open terminal

*Ctrl+Alt+T*

Use the command below to launch fdisk (as root user), a partition mount managing utility installed in Ubuntu by default.  This application can also be found in the Ubuntu Dash, I believe it's just called "Disks" or something like that.

*sudo fdisk*

Select the associated HDD, then the associated partition (which is not labelled "D" in Linux, because Linux doesn't use that naming convention).  Right click it for a list of options, including the ability to set automount parameters either automatically, or manually.  You can control the name of the partition in Linux, reformat/delete partitions, the mount location, mount options, etc.

Google search "How the Linux filesystem works" to find more information about the Linux file system.  I highly suggest it.

**How the Linux File System Works; *breif summary***

There are layers of software that mount filesystems.  Partitions are just digitally divided filesystems, allowing a computer to detect it as more than one device, but Linux can do all that and it can do it with **any** file system that can ever be created.  You can mount any partition in any format, and it will always successfully read the data.  Then it mounts it inside another filesystem.  One giant filesystem starting with / is the mapping strategy that Linux uses for all digital data, and it flawlessly mounts any hard drive format to it.

Exceptions, more like technicalities, would only include certain communication formats such as MTP, which I don't know much about, but it makes some very weird changes to filesystem management, and a second communication program has to be designed for it.

**TLDR;**

Your D:\ partition should be detectable by Linux automatically.  If it is not you should find out why, and use partition managing software and find the partition.  Use an application called disks if you search the unity dash for it, or fdisk if you run it from the terminal.  If this application shows an NTFS filesystem of the same size as your D:\ used to be, then just right click it, change the properties so that it automounts on boot.  It's really easy software, I can't write a guide for using it for you thats too much haha.  Go google it, if you still need help, there are many articles and videos out there about running powerful partition managers like fdisk on Ubuntu.  There is also existing support articles written about what to do if Linux isn't detecting a partition, and you should read some.

Comment: What I learned that the other partition should be /var filesystem.

This file system is specific to local systems. It is called as var because the data keeps changing. The sub directories include /cache/man (A cache for man pages), /games (any variable data belong to games), /lib (files that change), /log (log from different programs), /tmp (for temporary files).

I just cant know how to chnage the type of filesystem for that partition. Any ideas ?

Comment: There's much more than that.  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linux-filesystem/  This article published by IBM is an extremely in depth analysis of the linux filesystem, I'm studying it right now, maybe you're interested.  But to summarize, I'm just going to write an edit to the answer for you now.