# Replacing Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, windows, data-recovery

I have Windows 8.1 on my HP Pavilion G6 and would like to replace windows with Ubuntu 14.04 but what option do I choose when it comes to the installation part? I noticed it wont detect my Windows 8.1 so should that matter if im going to replace it with Ubuntu? Should i choose the Erase Disk option and then install? Secure Boot and Fastboot and all other options have been taken care of but would like some further instructions from someone a little more experienced.

Comment: Consider the question: [If I chose replace Windows with Ubuntu, do I lose the other partition too?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/306452/if-i-chose-replace-windows-with-ubuntu-do-i-lose-the-other-partition-too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the option labeled "Guided - Use entire disk and setup LVM"
and then keep clicking Yes or Next, then everything will install just fine.

keep in mind that this will erase everything on your disk.

Comment: so this will remove windows 8.1 and install ubuntu?

Comment: yes, it will. it will erase everything as i originally noted.

Comment: sorry for so many questions just wanna be carful but other then that is there any extra steps i should take before doing so?

Comment: dont worry about asking too many questions.
for the most part, everything can be fixed or fine-tuned post installation. whatever you dont do right during the installation and be changed later, with some effort. But as long as you choose "guided - use entire disk with lvm", and keep using the default options, you'll have a working installation when youre finished.

Comment: thank you and one last little question lets say i need to get windows 8 back can I use my recovery discs to get it back?

Comment: yes, you can use recovery disks, or download an official installer (iso) and use the CD-Key from the sticker on the bottom of your laptop, or it may be located under the battery.

Comment: i see Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation and Erase disk and install Ubuntu. Which option do i choose?

Comment: Can anyone answer this^

Answer (score 0):

> i see Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation and Erase disk and install Ubuntu. Which option do i choose?

Choose Erase disc and Install Ubuntu and make sure the other LVM Encryption option is selected below.  When it comes to re-installing Windows 8.1 if you have recovery discs you shouldn't have a problem re-installing Windows. If you don't have any recovery discs you can create them within Windows just do a search [Windows + S] at the desktop for recovery disc.  You will need 3 blank DVDs FYI.  Instead of getting rid of Windows completely you can always dual-boot your machine.  If you have yet to install Ubuntu you can re-partition your C: Drive, search for disc partitioner, and allocate some memory from the C: drive for Ubuntu.  Reboot and install Ubuntu on this new partition and you should have a dual booting machine with Windows & Ubuntu.  Of course if that seems too much for you installing Ubuntu solely by itself is the easiest thing to do.