# Can't find my other drives after installing over Windows

Tags: 16.04, context-menu

I replaced my Windows OS with Ubuntu. After a successful installation I can not find my other drives ( i.e. D, E, F, G ) and their contents in Ubuntu. Is it erased? I was not aware of that. Is there any way to get the contents back?

P.S. At the time of installation I clicked the "erase and replace windows", not "something else".

Comment: How many physical hard drives were in your machine?

Comment: only one physical drive

Comment: See [If I chose replace Windows with Ubuntu do I lose the other partitions too?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306452/if-i-chose-replace-windows-with-ubuntu-do-i-lose-the-other-partition-too)

Answer (score 1):

If you only had one physical drive in the machine that would indicate that when Windows was installed that drive was partitioned into C, D, E, F, and G.

When you installed Ubuntu it saw that single physical drive and treated it as a single physical drive. The "Erase and Replace Windows" then was acting on that drive.

Running `dh -h` will allow you to verify if all of the space on the drive was reused by the installation. Compare the output to the size of the physical drive.

Answer (score 0):

'erase and replace windows' .. erases Windows and replace it with Ubuntu.
So, Yes your Windows installation has been overwritten.

Comment: It showed it would erase all the files within the existing Os .Does that mean other drives too rather than c drive only ?

Comment: @A.Haldar it looks like it, take a look at your partitons with gparted, and see what's left.

Comment: If the other partitions (E: F:, etc) were on the same hard drive they were likely overwritten. Linux does not use letters to refer to partitions, it uses /dev/sdxy . gparted is a graphical program to show your partitions