# Please give me some information for doing partition

Tags: installation, partitioning, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's your recommendation on drive partitioning schemes for a desktop and home server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247/whats-your-recommendation-on-drive-partitioning-schemes-for-a-desktop-and-home)

I Want to install Ubuntu 12.04 in my PC
but i have no knowledge about doing 
**Partition** please give some informations for doing **PARTITION**
My system configuration is:

1. Hard disk 20Gb IDE
2. Processor:Intel(R)Pentim(R) 4 CPU 2.40Ghz
3. RAM : 1 GB

Comment: There are many duplicate questions like this here, so this one will likely be flagged for closure. Try a search here for [recommended partitioning](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=recommended+partitioning), or just go with the default suggestions. It's pretty easy and you should have no trouble getting Ubuntu installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about what to do, I'd recommend just follow the instructions of the installer and go with the partitioning suggested there, especially since you state yourself you are not an expert.

*But, please make sure you have saved all your important data since partitioning or reformatting a drive will lead to data loss.*

Messing about too much with partitioning is not a good idea on your machine anyway because Ubuntu has a minimum requirement of 15 GB (see the [System Requirement](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) page at [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com)), so just go with what is suggested during the installation process.

So if you are confronted with a screen like this during the installation http://www.linuxbsdos.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Uinstall1-600x413.png, go with one of the first three to options -- whichever you prefer and fits your needs.

You could also take a look at this guide to learn a little bit about partitioning http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/04/manual-disk-partitioning-guide-for-ubuntu-11-04/