# help me for doing partitioning

Tags: partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's your recommendation on drive partitioning schemes for a desktop and home server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247/whats-your-recommendation-on-drive-partitioning-schemes-for-a-desktop-and-home)

I Want to **install** Ubuntu 12.04 (a fresh installation) in my PC but i have no knowledge about doing Partition please give some informations for doing PARTITION

My system configuration is:

- Hard disk 20Gb IDE
- Processor:Intel(R)Pentim(R) 4 CPU 2.40Ghz
- RAM : 1 GB

i like to doing *partition* these like

1. > /  = 5 GB 
   >   swap = 2 GB 
   >   /boot = 5 GB 
   >   /home = 3 GB   (my files music, videos etc are saved in my pen drive or cd)
   >   /tmp  = 5 GB

Please guide or **advice** to me for doing **partitoning**

i don't know what happend doing partitioning without

> /boot

I would like to study about python and gtk programming

please advise me suitabe partition