# How to reset Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, 16.10

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and then upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10. But it's now bloated with remains of 5 DE and manually installed languages. Also, Pantheon has messed up Unity's GTK files and it's now looking broken. So I want to reset Ubuntu 16.04.1. Can it be done with the ISO??

Comment: The only way i know to reset ubuntu is to reinstall it again.

Comment: Can it be done **without damaging data** in the `/home` ???

Comment: I think so yes more info here -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/56051/reinstalling-ubuntu-without-formating-home-as-well-as-without-any-old-config-f#56070

Comment: You might!! be able to do it with tasksel by converting to server and then back to desktop which might preserve your home. But it will loose all your installed programs.

Comment: It is definitely possible to reinstall Ubuntu without deleting `HOME`:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/173506/is-there-any-other-way-to-do-a-clean-install-withot-formatting-home but to be on the safe side a backup would not hurt.

Comment: Can youu please post this as **answer**