# What is the best configuration while installing the Fresh Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's your recommendation on drive partitioning schemes for a desktop and home server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247/whats-your-recommendation-on-drive-partitioning-schemes-for-a-desktop-and-home)

I'm going to install fresh Ubuntu on my Laptop. But I some time ago I read somewhere that it is better to place ur home directory in other partition.

**If its better then what are the advantages it has over installing home directory in the same partition of System or should I say root.**

I will create two partitions for Ubuntu. One default for root and other partition for Other user. *And will I be able to install applications on second partition where the regular user account is available???.*

Please correct if I'm wrong .