# If i upgrade to ubuntu 13.04 from 12.04 will i lose my data and apps?

Tags: 13.04, updates

I haven't added any partition to my present system... will my files in folders like documents and apps be available after i update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is **no**. But it will be good to [make a backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216159/how-to-make-an-easy-complete-full-backup-including-all-configurations/216163#216163). See [Upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade).

Comment: @user171778 Just pay attention, the answer is applied when upgrading, not when install over.