# How to properly clone both root and user information with proper permissions?

Tags: backup, root, clone, user-management

I have been looking for a backup software for my Ubuntu boxes that works with the similar ease of EaseUs backup software for windows.  I would like to be able to back up both user info and root info. I have tried the built in backup in ubuntu without much luck and the same goes for clonezilla...Thanks!

EaseUs is almost a one click solution for Windows that backs up entire partitions even linux partitions.  It does not matter if the disk is encrypted or not.(to EaseUs)

The problem is that I want something that not only backs up partitions for my encrypted linux partitions plus my boot partition.  I want it to install grub if need be and also be loaded to dissimilar hardware.  (i.e. you buy a bigger harddrive and need to do a restore)

My entire setup currently is GPT partitioning

on sda1 I have a software raid drive that I have yet to be able to use in Ubuntu although I know it is possible.  (ntfs formatted but dynamic disk formatted from windows 8.1)

on sdb1 and 2 are special partitions required by windows 8.1 in gpt mode (one is system and the other is some weird thing for gpt)
on sdb3 I have my windows8.1 install
on sdb4 I have unallocated space for my ssd to be able to repair itself
on sdb5 I have an encrypted ext 4 partition containing root,user,etc
on sdb6 I have an unencrypted ext 2 partition containing boot for grub

on sdb3 I have the other part of the dynamic disk for windows mirrored in software raid 0 with a total of 2TB ntfs formatted

Comment: Clonezilla should be perfect. How did it fail you? What functionality are you missing?

Comment: dupe of [Comparison of backup tools](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools) and [How to make an easy complete full backup, including all configurations?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/216159/how-to-make-an-easy-complete-full-backup-including-all-configurations)

Comment: @terdon Clone Zilla does not seem to like full disk encryption..maybe I have missed something.

Comment: That's the kind of thing you should include in your question. You haven't mentioned encryption anywhere. Please [edit] your question and explain what features you need, we don't know what EaseUs does or how. You need to explain your requirements to us.

Comment: @terdon sorry update complete