# Partition installing ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, 13.04, partitioning

I am installing Ubuntu on 250GB space. Entire 250GB for ubuntu, I would like to know what would be recommended partition sizes, also couple of terms like logical and primary partition is also what I would like to know. The intended use is for a home desktop (4GB RAM) with an towards programming and development.

Any insights would be really appreciated.
(This may be a repeat question, although I did search the forum, would be really helpful if I could be pointed to the right reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good partition setup for this purpose:

- `swap`: 8 GB. This is very safe amount of swap space for your amount of RAM. It will enable the Suspend to Disk option, if your graphics driver supports it.
- `/`: 75 GB. Upon installation, only about 4-8 GB of this will be used. Many packages will have to be installed to provide a suitable environment for the developer using this computer, and much - but not all - of this space will be used.
- `/home`: 167 GB. This is very optional - in fact, unless you plan on installing a whole other Linux distro besides Ubuntu, it will be less complicated to simply include this with `/`.
- `/boot`: [On modern hardware it is not necessarily helpful to have a separate `/boot` partition.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247/whats-your-recommendation-on-drive-partitioning-schemes-for-a-desktop-and-home/3603#3603)

That said, to be perfectly honest, it is probably best to simply leave this up to the installer unless you have a specific reason for wanting to set up different partitions. Ubuntu setup now comes with the option to reinstall Ubuntu without overwriting `/home` or other local system folders.