# Is there anyway to Upgrade from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 without deleting any files?

Tags: installation, upgrade, 13.10

I am thinking like in the android phone way, you upgrade your OS but no files are gone. Is there anyway to do that??

Answer (score 1):

Well, there isn't a need to delete files in the first place.

- For normal users, you get a GUI dialog box pop up to ask if you want to upgrade to the newest release.
- The command line method is `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` or `sudo sed -i 's/raring/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y`.
- The CD method is simply clicking upgrade when asked how you want to install.

However, it's advisable to make a /home partition when you first install Ubuntu so you can always do a complete fresh install and still have all of your files.

Comment: There's no need to create a /home partition, one can always select advanced partitioning in the installer and install Ubuntu in the existing Ubuntu partition (it'll overwrite system files but not /home) See [this AU answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/3603/50272)

Comment: I'd always advise backing up before an upgrade.  You shouldn't lose anything but upgrades do occasionally go wrong and its much easier to fix with a backup.